# Cannot use string class to assign characters but works with char array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm trying to assign some characters from a `string` to another `string` as follows:

```
string s2;
int ind = -1;

for(int i = 0; i < ch; i++)
{
    s2[++ind] = s[i];
}

s2[++ind] = '\0';
```

Now when I try to print `s2` using

```
cout << s2 << endl;
```

It prints nothing on the black screen. But when I use `char` array in place of `string` declaration for `s2`, then `s2` gets printed successfully. I think both a `string` and `char` array's characters can be accessed in the same way. Cannot understand why this happened. Some info about this?

Comment: `std::string` is not a C string!

Comment: why do you need the 2 indices **i** and **ind**?

Comment: @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ, using two indices is no harm right?

Comment: @Jaya There's a potential memory and performance hit, it's also slightly less readable imo. You can declare `i` before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the `++ind`d element of an empty string. Use string's operator `+=` to append a `char` to the string.

Comment: You could also mention easier way of constructing string from char array (or other string) `std::string s2(s);` then this iteration.

Comment: @Filip Kočica, I am not taking all the characters, only some of the characters. I think `s2(s, s + ch);` works fine. Got it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains Undefined Behavior!

At the beginning your string size is zero and you do not resize it. As a result required memory is not allocated and proper information in `string` is not updated.
Small string optimization probably prevents a crash which should happen.

Two ways to fix it:

```
// crappy solution - to match your pattern
string s2;
for(int i=0;i<ch;i++)
{
    s2.push_back(s[i]);
}

// a good one
string s2(s, s + strlen(s));
```